# How can I trigger a VBA macro in Excel based on a value on a specific cell?

Tags: vba, triggers

I am quite new to VBA and I am not able to find the problem in my VBA trigger.
I have created multiple macros (which are working if manually triggered) and a trigger based on value change but it give me the "Compile Error: Type mismatch". Below, I am sharing the screen shots of my macros and the trigger. Could you please help me understanding where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

[Macro1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeeL6.png)`enter code here`
[Macro2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw0Ym.png)`enter code here`
[Macro3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIJAk.png)`enter code here`
[Macro4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ociju.png)`enter code here`
[trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUhyf.png)`enter code here`
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcAK3.png)`enter code here`

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of code: you can copy paste the code as text.

Comment: Target is a range. `set Target = Range("B9")` But it's usually better to check whether the target is B9, instead, otherwise we can assume it has not been changed, to not run the macro on every change. It's a type mismatch since you are basically giving it a string instead of a range.

Answer (score 0):

`Target` is a `range` and you are passing it a string.
`Range("B9")` is a range, `("B9")` is a string, Hence the  `Type mismatch` Error

If you are going to change the target anyway, there's no need to actually use it.

You could just do

```
If Range("B9").Value = "" Then
```

And to have to check even less, you can use Select Case:

```
Select Case Range("B9").Value
    Case ""

    Case 1

    Case 2

    Case 3

End Select
```

If you only want to run the code when the changed cell is `B9`, you can use the `intersect` method:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case target.Value
    ..........
```

If intersect returns something, it means the ranges intersect, so we aren't interested in ***what*** it returns, but ***if***. That's why we use the "Not" and "Nothing"